# Do you say "please yourself" in a non-sexual context?

Tags: phrases, verbs, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

In an English grammar textbook, I found this example sentence:

> Dinner's at 8 o'clock, but there's nothing planned for the afternoon,
>   so you can all **please yourself** until then.

I googled *please yourself* and it seems to mean *masturbation* in some contexts. Do native English speakers use it in non-sexual contexts like the example above?

Comment: [Do whatever you want](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/please-yourself), [I don't care](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/please_2)

Comment: Ricky Nelson found it appropriate in his song Garden Party: "You can't please everyone, so you've got to please yourself"

Comment: I would use the phrase "suit yourself" instead. "Dinner's at 8 o'clock, but there's nothing planned for the afternoon, so you can all suit yourselves until then." But then I'm a native American English speaker, so...

Comment: "you can all _do as you like_ until then" seems the most idiomatic in AE. (added it as an answer)

Comment: "Entertain yourselves" suggested below is another AE alternative which is definitely not sexual.

Comment: @Em1 _Do whatever you want_ is good, but _I don't care_ would sound really rude in this sentence, unless you say it _really_ nicely

Comment: You found this in a grammar book? I’d take everything in that grammar book with a heavy dose of salt. “You can all please yourself” is **completely ungrammatical**. Singular _yourself_ is not used with plural _you_, and the _all_ here makes it completely unambiguous that this is a plural _you_. The sentence should be, “You can all please **yourselves**”.

Comment: In Australia the more common phrase is "suit yourself" (eg. "I'll take the long way round, if you don't mind..." "Suit yourself."). I would find it a little strange if someone said "please yourself" in that same context, but I definitely wouldn't interpret that to mean masturbation.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

*[Please](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/please_2)* is simply a verb that means *give pleasure*. There is nothing to forbid the word from being used in a non-sexual context, and this is usually the case.

> **Please** yourselves by browsing the books on the shelves.

Comment: Another common expression is "You can *do as you please* until then."

Comment: I believe the OPs own googling disproved the idea that "this is usually the case."

Comment: @JoshuaDrake More than 50% of the internet's traffic is porn. This is not true of offline communication. Ergo, Google results are not representative of how language is used. Self-evidently, they're only representative of how language is used *online*.

Comment: @JasperLoy and SevenSidedDie Although the OPs example shows that it has/d another meaning language is defined by its current common usage, and the internet is certainly the farthest reaching lexicon available.

Answer (score 34):

In British English, *please yourself* is always non-sexual. The sexual variant is *pleasure yourself*.

Joshua Drake has commented that it's different in American English, which might explain the OP's Google results, and KitFox's book quotes. Happy to edit this answer to reflect dialectal differences.

Comment: I disagree strongly. Not *always*, just *usually*.

Comment: @KitFox: Of 26 written instances of [he was pleasing himself](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22he+was+pleasing+himself%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22he+was+pleasing+himself%22&hl=en&tbo=1&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:2000,cd_max:2099&tbm=bks&ei=hbnIT_-ZCMjX8QOb3unfDw&start=20&sa=N&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=1fba3d7991298238&biw=1258&bih=842), only two are even in a sexual context at all. In one he's pleasing himself about how he uses *her* body, and in the other he's masturbating the way *he* wants (i.e. - it specifically means he's **suiting himself**, in both cases).

Comment: [At least one instance](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=UKhwOjWC4WYC&pg=PA157&dq=%22he+pleased+himself%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=4sDIT5_AAoXm0QHexZGHAQ&ved=0CEoQ6AEwBDgy#v=onepage&q=%22he%20pleased%20himself%22&f=false) as a euphemism for masturbation.

Comment: [Also specifically 'please yourself'](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=1PBSf7oRLfgC&pg=PT124&dq=%22do+you+please+yourself%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=0sHIT_KVIKe_0AG6-6CJAQ&sqi=2&ved=0CFQQuwUwBQ#v=onepage&q=%22do%20you%20please%20yourself%22&f=false) as a euphemism for masturbation.

Comment: But the very next paragraph in *Bloodlines* contains "Andersen's" as a plural, which might be an indication of writing/editing quality. (The second example doesn't link to the text for me, probably a copyright issue)

Comment: I can't follow KitFox's last link, but he/she assures me that it says --- "You are not so great a lover as your reputation." She had not meant to say that.  One did not say such things to men.  "You hurry." // "No point giving you time to think.  Do you please yourself?  With your own hands?" // "What do you mean?" But she knew what he meant.

Comment: As a native American English speaker this answer is incorrect.

Comment: As a native British English speaker this is exactly how I see the phrase. I've never seen it used in a sexual manner. In fact that's what intrigued me so much about he header. And the phrase pleasure yourself is nearly always a sexual term.

Answer (score 11):

Most commonly, it is used in a non-sexual context.  "Masturbation" is kind of a specialist use of the phrase, and certainly doesn't apply here.  Googling "please yourself" may have given you results that were unreasonably skewed.

Comment: -1: Masturbation isn't even a "specialist" use of the phrase *"please yourself"* - which as @Andrew says is *always* non-sexual. The sexual variant is always *"pleasure yourself"*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I believe you are incorrect.  I could post a link here, but I won't.  The title of the link that I contemplated posting was "How to please yourself down there".  I haven't clicked it, but I don't expect it to refer to visiting Australia.

Comment: I've no doubt that usage you cite is "tongue-in-cheek". If you personally use *"please yourself"* to mean *"masturbate"* I can't very well say you don't, but no significant number of native speakers would understand you unless the context was unmistakeable. In which case even if they *did* understand, almost all native speakers would think *"I wonder why he used that odd form of words?"*

Comment: "I was expecting my boyfriend to come over tonight, but he called and cancelled, so now I'm just going to have to run a long bath and please myself".  I can't imagine that any native speaker would find this sentence odd.  Inappropriate perhaps, but not odd.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: so is it 'always' or just sometimes. Even your investigatino showed some counter examples. The claim of the OP is that they found "some contexts" where it is sexual and therefore the question. Are you saying 'shouldn't" or "isn't" and if the latter how do you account for the counter-examples?

Comment: @Mitch: I use *"always non-sexual"* to mean that in my understanding, competent native speakers know that the standard idiomatic "euphemism" for masturbation is *pleasuring oneself*, not *pleasing oneself*. As I said, David's counter-example is jocular/facetious - if it were written in all seriousness (KitFox seems to have found one) I'd simply say the writer isn't a competent native speaker.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: That is a non-standard use of 'always'. What a competent native speaker 'knows' is unavailable to us, but utterances are. And there are some counterexamples. So, in my dialect of English, I would not use 'always', but 'mostly' or 'almost always' or 'usually but the alternate also occurs often'. Also, either phrase is not particularly common, so that many 'competent native speakers' would only vaguely perceive the prurient connotation.

Comment: @Mitch: To *pleasure oneself* is now pretty dated, but the "masturbation" meaning is firmly established, and I'm surprised you think it's "uncommon". Given how many visitors here aren't native speakers, I think it's a bad idea to even *mention* the one-in-a-million times where someone uses *please yourself* in that context. *Please yourself* is also common, but [virtually?!] always means *suit yourself, do whatever you want*. David's answer here suggests it might have a sexual connotation, which I think is simply misleading - for all practical purposes, it doesn't.

Answer (score 8):

You can also use it in an idiomatically exasperated fashion:

"Do you want to come to the beach with me?"

"No."

"Come on, it'll be fun."

"Don't want to."

"Oh, *please yourself*!" <**stomps off in a huff**>

In this idiom, "please yourself" means "do whatever you like, then, see if I care!"  It definitely doesn't mean "go <*expletive deleted*> yourself"...

Comment: I think it’s the same as “Whatever!” — which, while not particularly pleasant, certainly isn’t masturbatory.

Comment: I think "suit yourself" is a better idiom in this context, but then I am not a native english speaker.

Answer (score 3):

"Please yourself," "do whatever you want", "entertain yourselves" ...all sound a bit out of place in your sentence (to my American ear). I would expect to hear "you may all *do as you like* until then."

Answer (score 1):

Yes - English speakers use the phrase "please yourself" in non-sexual contexts. There may be sexual interpretations, but the phrase on its own would not usually mean that unless there were other hints in the context.

"You can please yourself" usually means: you can make your own choice about what to do. This by contrast with situations where you are expected to do what the group is doing, or the choice is somehow otherwise made by someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that you could *entertain* yourselves for the afternoon, which just means to do something fun to avoid boredom.

Answer (score -2):

It's pretty much used in the same way as 'help yourself,' Which is can also be used for referencing masturbation (in Dutch, that is). It's like Oscar Wilde said: "Dirty mind is a joy forever"; you can give anything a sexual flavor if you want.

Comment: No - "help yourself" and "please yourself" are different. To please  yourself generally means to make your own choice about something. And although the Dutch equivalent of "help yourself" means to masturbate, this association doesn't exist in English.

Comment: *Please yourself* means ***do** whatever you want*, whereas *help yourself* means ***take** whatever you want*.